# Why is verb (plain, dictionary form) + だろう/でしょう/であろう grammatical?

Tags: copula, modality

To my (limited) knowledge, one has to put the nominalizer `の/ん` between a verb and a copula. However, when I was learning the usage of である, the written, literary copula, I read that `であろう` can follow a verb directly. That was when I realized that `だろう/でしょう` works in the same fashion.

I understand that の/ん is optional context-wise in this case, but how come the so-called volitional form does not need to have the preceding verb nominalized?

Comment: I wonder if you're not getting an answer to this because the answer to most questions about grammar is just, "That's how it works." Other elements can also attach to a verb in plain form: じゃない？、かもしれない、に違いない、as well as sentence-ending particles. Note that many of these serve to add a level of doubt or certainty.

Comment: I sort of suspected that it had something to do with the question being a no-brainer, or overly noobish. You could well be right though. In any case, I didn't know one could attach じゃない (and ではない as well?)  to a plain verb. Is this considered grammatical practice?

Comment: Yes, absolutely grammatical everyday Japanese.

Comment: http://maggiesensei.com/2013/02/13/how-to-use-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-janai%E3%80%80%EF%BC%86%E3%80%80%E3%80%9C%E3%82%93%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-njanai/

Comment: だろう and でしょう in general behave in their own way and don't seem to work like other forms of the copula. For example, "寒いだろう" isn't felt to be as agrammatical as "寒いだ".  Many people consider だろう/でしょう to be distinct mood particles at this point.